# Mutex in Silverlight

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight

Are thre Mutex's that can be used in Silverlight?
It seems the Mutex examples I have seen work in window forms but not in silverlight.

In using System.Threading there does not seem to be a Mutex class in Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for them. Use the `lock` keyword.

They are in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7.1 Mango.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: I want to know about this lock keyword.  It sounds like it would do the job.

Comment: I am trying the example of lock here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for anyone else visiting here, Microsoft didn't include the Reference to mscorlib.extensions in the template project.  So open your project, Right click on "References" in the solution explorer, pick "add Reference", and in the ".Net" tab there's mscorlib.Extensions.  The Mutex class is in that extensions file.